# Particular Solution Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this problem:

$$y''''-3y'''+3y''-y'=6t-20$$

I am attempting the method of undetermined coefficients and the particular solution is supposed to be $y_p(t)= at^2+bt$. Could anyone explain why the particular solution is $y_p(t)= at^2+bt$?

Comment: Is your question, why a quadratic?  That's because the first derivative of a quadratic is linear, second derivative is a constant, so the differential operator on the left will return a linear function, as desired.  Or is your question, what no constant term?  In which case the answer is that the constant term would be killed by the operator on the left so it doesn't help.

Comment: @AB408: We have $m^4 -3 m^3 + 3 m^2 - m = 0 \implies m_{1,2} = 0, 1$. If we choose $y_p = a + b t$, that does not account for the root $m = 1$, so we have to multiply $y_p$ by $t$ and thus choose $y_p = t( a + b t)$.